# On JBoss AS 7.1.1, why does Hibernate's AnnotationBinder not detect annotated entities?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, migration, jboss7.x

I'm trying to migrate a Spring application from JBoss AS 4.0.5.GA to 7.1.1.Final. In my `jboss-spring.xml` there is one bean, `engine`, whose init method results in the `createQuery` row below being executed.

```
public class QueueConfigurationDAO {
    private EntityManager _entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        _entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public List<QueueConfiguration> getQueueConfigurations() {
        Query query = _entityManager.createQuery("from QueueConfiguration");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

This results in the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in "/C:/Users/Emil/JBoss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standal
one/deployments/zz10-wf.spring/META-INF/jboss-spring.xml": Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.i
nternal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: QueueConfiguration is not mapped [from QueueConfiguration]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.jboss.spring.factory.NamedXmlApplicationContext.<init>(NamedXmlApplicationContext.java:69)
        at org.jboss.spring.factory.NamedXmlApplicationContext.<init>(NamedXmlApplicationContext.java:59)
        at org.jboss.spring.deployers.as7.SpringBootstrapProcessor.deploy(SpringBootstrapProcessor.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: QueueConfiguration is not mapped [from QueueConfiguration]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1348)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
        at $Proxy118.createQuery(Unknown Source)        at se.sunstone.workflow.queues.QueueConfigurationDAO.getQueueConfigurations(QueueConfigurationDAO.java:28)
        at se.sunstone.workflow.queues.StandardQueueManager.configure(StandardQueueManager.java:71)
        at se.sunstone.workflow.queues.StandardQueueManager.start(StandardQueueManager.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy121.start(Unknown Source)      at se.sunstone.workflow.engine.ExecutionEngine.start(ExecutionEngine.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1614)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: QueueConfiguration is not mapped [from QueueConfiguration]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3252)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3141)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:550)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:285)
        ... 48 more
```

I suppose that `QuerySyntaxException: QueueConfiguration is not mapped` means that my

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "queue_configuration")
public class QueueConfiguration { /* ... */ }
```

class is not recognized as an entity by Hibernate. Indeed, when I run the application in JBoss 4, the startup logs contain rows like

```
INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: se.sunstone.workflow.queues.QueueConfiguration
```

but no such rows appear in the log when I try to deploy it in JBoss 7. If I comment out the `engine` bean from `jboss-spring.xml`, the application happily deploys without exceptions.

I'm using JBoss 7's built-in Hibernate module and I'm deploying my webapp using the Snowdrop module. I have monkeyed around with this for a few days now, including trying to use Hibernate 3 instead, but the problem persists.

If I explicitly specify `<class>se.sunstone.workflow.queues.QueueConfiguration</class>` in `persistence.xml`, the application deploys and the logs now contain the same AnnotationBinder rows as when running on JBoss 4. However, the application also has a bunch of other annotated entities, whose DAOs are omitted from the configs below, and they are not detected unless I specify them too in `persistence.xml`. Apparently the AnnotationBinder does not detect my annotated entities unless I specify them in `persistence.xml`. Why is that?

### Details

Archive layout:

```
zz10-wf.spring
-- META-INF
---- jboss-deployment-structure.xml
---- jboss-spring.xml
---- jpa-persistence.xml
---- MANIFEST-MF
-- (Java package hierarchy)
```

Following [these instructions](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Spring+applications+development+and+migration+guide#Springapplicationsdevelopmentandmigrationguide-UsingSpringmanagedpersistenceunits) I have renamed the traditional `persistence.xml` to `jpa-persistence.xml` so that JBoss will not detect it and launch its own Hibernate instance.

`zz10-wf.spring` is currently deployed as an exploded directory, but the same thing happens if I deploy it as an uncompressed zip archive.

`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

`jboss-spring.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

  <!-- =========  Central application configuration  ========= -->
  <bean id="queueManager" class="se.sunstone.workflow.queues.StandardQueueManager"> 
    <property name="queueConfigurationDAO" ref="queueConfigurationDAO"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="engine" class="se.sunstone.workflow.engine.ExecutionEngine" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">  
    <property name="queueManager" ref="queueManager"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- =========  DAOs  ========= -->
  <bean id="queueConfigurationDAO" class="se.sunstone.workflow.queues.QueueConfigurationDAO" /> 

  <!-- =========  JPA  ========= -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="workflow" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven />

  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/WorkflowDS"/>

</beans>
```

`jpa-persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="workflow">
      <!-- <class>se.sunstone.workflow.queues.QueueConfiguration</class> -->
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have tried moving configuration details back and forth between `jpa-persistence.xml` and the `entityManagerFactory` bean definition, the results are largely the same and the application agrees to run with this minimal `jpa-persistence.xml` as long as the `QueueConfiguration` row above is uncommented.

Comment: Another poor soul with the same problem: [Thread 1](https://community.jboss.org/message/639279) [Thread 2](https://community.jboss.org/thread/175615)

Answer (score 1):

In an [earlier incarnation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17019485/9) of this question, one of my questions was why AnnotationBinder ran twice. I think this was because JBoss detected `persistence.xml` and launched its own Hibernate instance in parallel to the one launched by Spring. After renaming `persistence.xml` to `jpa-persistence.xml` (any other name would probably do, though) as described [in the JBoss AS 7 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Spring+applications+development+and+migration+guide#Springapplicationsdevelopmentandmigrationguide-UsingSpringmanagedpersistenceunits), this behaviour stopped. The problem with AnnotationBinder not detecting annotated entities persists, however.

I edited these questions out of the Question since I want the Question to be more specifically about why the AnnotationBinder does not detect annotated entities.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update "entityManagerFactory" bean in jboss-spring.xml as follows:

- remove "persistenceXmlLocation" property
- add "packagesToScan" property as following:

Sample (replace "your_jpa_related_base_package" with actual one):

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<!--
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/>
-->
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="your_jpa_related_base_package" />
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="workflow" />

<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Sorry, still no luck. I've moved on to other issues for the time being, I may return to this one later.